# JavaScript, string split, a number (can be float) and string

Tags: javascript

For example, how can I get "1.2" and "kg" for `x` in the following example? Currently, I get "", "1.", and "kg".

```
function split()
{
    var data = "1.2kg";
    var x = data.split(/([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+/);
}
```

Comment: Instead of split, would capture groups (non-letters)(letters) do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```js
function split()
{
    var data = "1.2kg";
    var x = data.match(/[\d\.]+|\D+/g);
    console.log(x);
}
split();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```js
let [value,unit] = data.match(/^[0-9.]*|[a-z]*$/g)
```

Obviously it's not an enterprise grade solution. If more then one dot, nonalpha characters, uppercase letters appears in input, the result may vary.

```
['1.2kg',
 '1.2 kg',
 '10.0.0.2 IP',
 '1 square méter' ].map(
    data => data.match(/^[0-9.]*|[a-z]*$/g)
  )
```

Comment: It works, but it creates 3 elements, of which the last element is an empty string. I can ignore the last one, but why does it create 3?

Comment: match creates always array . Then if you use  match rather than replace than you can take first element of array

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this with `parseFloat`, if you need float value, there is no need for regex.

```js
var data = "1.2kg"; 
console.log(parseFloat(data)) // 1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use match and not split. :-)

```
var data = "1.2kg";
var m = data.match(/[.0-9]+/);
console.log(m[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function split()
{
    var data = "hello world";
    var x = data.split(/\s/);
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = x
}
split()
```

```html
<span id="test"></span>
```

If you look at this simplified post, you will see it removes the item it is matched on. So I don't think split is what you want. what is the variation on the format? You could use simple regex to remove the number?

```js
function doWork() { 
            var str = "1.2kg"; 
            var matches = str.match(/(\d+)\.{0,1}(\d)/); 
              
            if (matches) { 
                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML 
                        = matches[0]; 
            } 
        } 
        
        doWork()
```

```html
<p>String is "1.2kg"</p> 
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, but I got this to work:

```
var x = data.split(/([0-9]*[.]*[0-9])/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: `parseFloat` and `slice` (using `findIndex`)

```js
const parseAndSplitQuantity = s => `${parseFloat(s)} ${
  s.slice( [...s].findIndex( v => /[^0-9|.]/.test(v) ) ) }`;

["1.2kg", "23.45Mb", "100Pound", "20.34Dollar", "23187.22Miles"]
  .forEach( str => console.log(`${str} => ` + parseAndSplitQuantity(str)) );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```